# SQLcipher Android: Multiple databases

Tags: android, sqlcipher

I want to make my program have multiple databases, each with their own password.  How do I do this? With the ATTACH command? Do databases have to be attached to each other?  Or can they just exist separately?  Or does ATTACHing cause nested SQLcipher DBs?  I'm currently using code similar to https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsSecure .  Could anybody provide any code that shows how this would work in a simple example?  Like suppose we were to start with the ConstantsSecure app, and how would we modd it into having two similar databases, each with different passcodes?  Is each database specified via a URI in that example?  Such as by the CONTENT_URI attribute?

Answer (score 0):

While you could use the `ATTACH` command to attach another database to another, you may wish to simply manage a separate connection to the other database.